# Google plus share opens link in browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-plus

I am just trying to implement an iPhone app, that has a feature to share on `Google+`. So, when I click on share button, it is opening the link in safari. Instead, I would like to have it like `Facebook` pop-up window. Is there any possibility to implement it?

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender {

    share = [[[GooglePlusShare alloc] initWithClientID:kClientID] autorelease];
    /*   share.delegate = self; // optional
     appDelegate.share = share; //optional*/

    [[[[share shareDialog] setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL_TO_SHARE"]] setPrefillText:descStr] open];

    [[share shareDialog] open];
}
```

This is the code, I’ve used for sharing. And I look up on the GooglePlusShare class, I couldn’t figure out anything possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , right now , this is the preffered way to post on google plus..And 
After all. after posting status on google plus..it also comes back to your app..

Comment: Yep. I know it would come back to app after posting. So there is no way to implement this, huh. Thank you Amit.